# I'm trying to open another jframe from a button using the setVisibility() method, there is no error thrown but it does nothing happens

Tags: java, swing

I've build a jframe but when I click on a button to go to another frame nothing happens even though no errors are thrown.  I've used the addActionListener, actionPerformed, and the setVisible(true) on an instance of the second jframe.

here is my code:

```
public class JhomeMain extends JFrame {

    private JPanel contentPane;
    private JTextField txtNameOfCoupon;
    private JTextField textField;
    private JTextField textField_1;
    private JTextField textField_2;
    private JTextField textField_3;
    private JLabel lblNameOfProduct;
    private JLabel lblDiscountRate;
    private JLabel lblValidDays;
    private JLabel lblValidationStatus;
    private JButton btnNewButton;
    private JButton btnView;
    private JLabel lblNewLabel_1;
    private JLabel lblNewLabel_2;
    private JTextField textField_4;
    private JLabel lblNewLabel_3;
    private JLabel lblNewLabel_4;
    private JLabel lblNewLabel_5;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
```

The main method is here

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {        

        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    JhomeMain frame = new JhomeMain();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });


    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public JhomeMain() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 970, 655);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBackground(new Color(135, 206, 250));
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(null);

        lblNewLabel_3 = new JLabel("Coupons Processing System");
        lblNewLabel_3.setBounds(324, 10, 266, 22);
        lblNewLabel_3.setFont(new Font("Lucida Grande", Font.BOLD, 18));
        contentPane.add(lblNewLabel_3);

        // ...
```

Here is the problematic part below:
Start

```
        btnView = new JButton("View");
        btnView.setBounds(584, 545, 82, 29);
        contentPane.add(btnView);
        btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
          public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
          {
              //closing the current window
              //frame.dispose();

              Jsecond second = new Jsecond();
              second.setVisible(true);
          }

        });
}
```

End of problematic part

Comment: Your frame is destroyed immediately afterwards since it’s a local variable and doesn’t need to exist later

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others. It should show that the `actionPerformed()` method is called, but that the create frame is not shown. Keep in mind to keep the MCVE *minimal*.

Comment: 1) *"another jframe"* See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556) 2) Java GUIs have to work on different OS', screen size, screen resolution etc.  using different PLAFs in different locales.  As such, they are not conducive to pixel perfect layout.  Instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) along with layout padding and borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17874718/418556).